# Google Analytics tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true) doesnt show exceptions in logcat

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics, android-logcat

I am currently using `play-services-analytics:7.5.0` in my android project. In my application class I have initialized the GoogleAnalytics sdk and for the `Tracker` object I have enabled exception reporting configuration:

`tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);`

**Problem**

When an exception is thrown and the app crashes the logcat doesnt show anything (shows only `D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM`), also the screen stays black and freezes.

If I remove this line, then the crash happens normaly and it is shown in logcat.

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to play-services-analytics version 8.1.0 solved the issue for me.

Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```

You might need to upgrade "Google play services" and "Google Repository" from your SDK manager.